# How can I use painkillers?

Tags: game-boy-advance, max-payne

I'm playing Max Payne on Game Boy Advance lately for nostalgia, and I keep finding painkillers, however, I can't find a way to use them. There used to be a button for it on PC, but I can't seem to find a way to do it on GBA, I tried pressing every single button, but none worked.

How can I use painkillers in Max Payne (on GBA)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more tries, I figured it out:

You can use Painkillers with the <kbd>Select</kbd> button.